# residue calculus / rational function = $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

So we know that if
$f(z) = \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$, whereas $deg(Q) \geq deg(P) + 2$, then
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = 2 \pi i \sum_{ Im k > 0} \text{Res}_k f(z)$, but now the exercise is as follows:

> Let f(z) be a rational function function which does not have any poles
> on the real axis and which has a zero of order 1 at $\infty$ (i.e
> $deg(Q) =deg(P) + 1$), argue why the limit $\lim_{R \to \infty}
>  \int_{-R}^{R} f(x) dx$ still exists and determine the difference
> $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^{R} f(x) dx$ - $ 2 \pi i \sum_{
>  \text{Im k} > 0} \text{Res}_k f(z)$.

(Im k = imaginary part of the k-th pole)
So I assume that when the zero at $\infty$ is of order 1, then the integral won't be absolutely convergent anymore? but what exactly guarantees its existence and how could I proceed calculating the difference?

Comment: because you can integrate on a contour consisting of the segment $[-R,R]$ and the half circle of radius $R$ in the upper plane say; but on the half circle $dz=iRd\theta$ so the integrand becomes a continuous function of the type $c+O(1/R)$ (on a finite $\theta$ interval) so goes to constant (essentially the ratio of the leading terms of $P,Q$), hence the original real integral converges as the difference is finite given by the residues

Comment: @Conrad: thank you very much, so just be sure that I have understood it correctly, on the half circle we parameterize with $z =Re^{i \phi}$, $\phi \in [0,\pi]$, when dividing the fraction by the highest power (let deg(Q)=n+1, so deg(P)=n) we have a function of the form $c + O(1/R)$, taking the limit results in a constant). But Is there any way to calculate the difference explicitly?

Comment: that difference is more or less the limit of the integral on the half circle so that constant - note that by Cauchy/residue theorem the integral of $P/Q$ on the closed curve made out of the real segment and the half circle is precisely $2 \pi i \sum_{ Im k > 0, |k|<R} \text{Res}_k f(z)$ and taking $R$ large enough, we encompass all poles

Comment: @Conrad: thank you very much

Comment: happy to be of help